# How to redirect non logged in users to Login page on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I know this is a question asked million times but I can't find an answer that is either fitting the version of Wordpress now and/or my particular case.

I have a Wordpress website with Buddypress installed on it.

I want that :
- Not logged in users can see only the page wp-login.php
- Logged in users can access the whole website

I just can't figure it out, it is impossible. Either I change the site address or assign a page, or fuctions... Nothing works, all the time an error or a 404 page error etc...

Basically : you arrive on the website, you are not logged in = Wp-Login.php, if you are logged in page "members"

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do this based on what your ultimate goal is (use WP login page, a custom login page, etc...). You can try adding this to your theme's functions.php file:

```
if ( ( is_single() || is_front_page() || is_page() || is_archive() || is_tax() )
    && ! is_page( 'login' ) && ! is_page('register') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    auth_redirect(); 
}
```

Or you can use the plugin, [Force Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/)

**UPDATE**

Theoretically, you can probably just use this, just haven't tested...

```
if( ! is_page('login') && ! is_page('register') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    auth_redirect(); 
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment, I already tried this method and it gives an error 500 immediately after...

Comment: This is why showing your code, and letting us know what you've already done, is a very helpful thing...  If you are getting a 500 error when trying this, it's a much larger problem.  Can you provide anything extra???

Comment: I just add it to the end of the function.php file, the file is the core function.php file, nothing has changed because I am testing also on a fresh simple Wordpress website...
Also, I would love to use the "force plugin" but people can't create an account because the register page is redirected to the login too when using these plugins...

Comment: Have you tried one of the plugins I mentioned?  And it would be helpful to show your functions.php file to see what else is going on in there...

Comment: Yes I tried and it prevents the users from creating an account if I do this, indeed, the register page is locked too with these "force login" plugins...

I would love to post the functions.php file but it is too long and doesn't fit in stackoverflow... That is the basic function.php file thought, like... the ORIGINAL ONE from wordpress, nothing changed, straight from archive...

Comment: Ha, wait a second, now it works with a different theme (not a core wordpress one), it is getting closer. So now how can I prevent them to access the Register page with your code in first comment ?
Thank you !

Comment: Updated code to include the register page... let me know if it's working

Comment: Thank you for spending some time ! This time, if I replace by the code your provided, it doesn't do anything. The website is just displaying regularly, nothing is hidden to anybody, maybe an error ?

Comment: Just took the code to the update, now it is an infinite loop, it crashes the server after a few seconds because the loop goes infinitely and too fast

Comment: Tried the plugin and tweaked it with your code ;) Thanks

Comment: @DanielC what filter/action are you putting this code in to make it work?

Comment: As noted by @trainoasis this does not work because you did not added the function to an hook. So this function in the file functions.php is simply not called.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look here

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-auth_redirect-to-specific-page

```
<?php
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect('http://somepagehere');
    exit;
}
?>
```

You can also add this to your functions.php file instead of what I said before:

```
function admin_redirect() {
if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
   wp_redirect( home_url('/{custom page goes here}/') );
   exit;
}
}
add_action('get_header', 'admin_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this  wordpress plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-user-access/
to control who can/ can't access your website.

You may get tons of similar plugins if you googled it.

Comment: Hello and thank you, however, none of the 20 plugins (including this one that is probably the worst, with super slow functions and breaking half of the pages of the website) is working. Either it simply doesn't work or block partially some pages or all of them including the register page... And that's a problem... 
I can't believe there is NOTHING easy to use : you are guest you login or register, else, welcome to the website. I mean, come on !

Comment: tried this one? https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

What you want it to check if the user is not currently trying to login or register, if not redirect them to whatever page you'd like.

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( 'login' ) && ! is_page('register') ) {
   //redirect user, create account with them, do a hoola-hoop
}
```

Be sure to place this code in your page file before get_header();