# how to force login via a custom login to restrict visitors from viewing a wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, hook, wordpress-login

I have built a custom login page to replace the default WordPress Login Page via a custom plugin - Referencing website:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-1-replace-the-login-page--cms-23627

This is an awesome plugin tutorial, as it does what I need for a client's website, however, now I am trying to find a solution that forces website visitors to be redirected to the newly created custom login page to prevent anyone from seeing any another pages/posts on the site without first logging in. I hope that this makes sense.

I have tried many of the WordPress' force login plugins without success, as these create errors of too many redirects issues.

Can anyone solve this??

Thank you in advance....

Comment: This existing answer will work too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34188644/3730754

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hi hope you already created a custom login page, next please place below code to your themes function.php file

```
function admin_redirect() {
if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
   wp_redirect( home_url('custome page slug') );
   exit;
}
}
add_action('get_header', 'admin_redirect');
```

Above code will check if a user is logged in or not, if not logged in then will redirect to given url.

Comment: Hi Ashkar,

Yes, I had already created the custom login page.
Thank you for this bit of code.... it did the trick... Thank you greatly

Comment: Glad to know this code helped you Jayral :)

Comment: This answer is the exact copy of this older existing one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34188644/3730754