# How to redirect to "login page" or "buy page" depending on user login status

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a page where there is a button named buy.While clicking the buy button its suppose to goto buy page if the user is logged in or to login page if the user is not logged in. I am trying to implement this using "is_user_logged_in()". I have tried "header:location" which gives me a warning since i have written for get_header() initially. i have tried it using javascript but nothing seems to work.here is my code please help me.

```
<script>

function myfunction() {
    location.reload();
}    

function redirect() {
    <?php if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        ?>
  window.location.replace("login.php");
  <?php
}else{
    ?>
    window.location.replace("buy.php");
    <?php }
    ?>

}
}
</script>
<?php
get_header();
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" id="show" onclick="myfunction()">
<input type="submit" name="buy" value="Buy Now" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="redirect()">

</div>
```

Comment: You can't use PHP headers after send data as a response in PHP. You have to use headers before all text and html outputs.

Comment: try this ==> `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write a JS just to check user login status and redirect accordingly. You can do as directed below.

At top of page before get_header() you can write this.

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
   auth_redirect();
}
```

This if condition checks the user if logged in it will continue to load rest of the page and if user is not logged in it will force user to get authenticated via login page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onClick, you can just put this php script on the top of the page.

```
if(isset($_POST['buy'])){
   if(is_user_logged_in()){
       header("Location:buy.php");
       exit();
    }
   else{
       header("Location:login.php");
       exit();
    }
}
```

//This code must be placed before any output is produced / Should be placed at the top

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( 'login' ) && ! is_page('register') ) {
   //redirect user, create account with them, do a hoola-hoop
}
```

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/44166973/4573789